# awk printing only last lines from a text file list

Tags: awk

I am trying to remove duplicate sets (four lines for each entry- first line identifies the set) from a file. I have a file of all uniq first lines (grep'ed common symbol in all first lines, sorted and ran uniq). I thought I could use awk to essentially rebuild my file with only unique entries. I used this command:

```
 awk -F '\t' 'NR==FNR {id[$1]; next} $1 in id' list_uniques.txt file_with_dups.fastq
```

However, output is only the last entry in the list_uniques.txt, and no additional lines. Clearly I am missing the command to print the next three lines after the first one, and also I have no idea why it is skipping to the end.

Comment: Please, just post the source file and expected output.

Comment: not sure but don't you have to assign `id[$1]` to something?

Comment: without the input file and expected output, you're making very hard to help you...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, no, he/she hasn't. Any reference to an array element in `awk` **automatically creates** that array element, as explained in a **NOTE** [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Reference-to-Elements).

Comment: @Horvathdp, once you have found a line, you only have to print it and read and print the three next lines: `print; for(i=3;i>0;i--) { getline; print }`